# Getting 200 ok response but username and password fields are empty its again redirecting to login page

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, scripting, webrequest

Getting 200 ok response but username and password fields are empty its again redirecting to login page can you help me on this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like  Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36   Edg/118.0.2088.61'
}

Payload = {
    "utf8": "✓",
    "spree_user[email]":     "yavixe4893@tutoreve.com",
    "spree_user[password]":   "Qwerty@123",
    "spree_user[remember_me]": "0",
    "commit": "Login",
}

with requests.Session() as ses:
    Url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.com"
    Req = ses.get(Url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Req.content,   'html5lib')
    print(Req.content)
    Payload['authenticity_token'] = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'csrf-token'})['content']
    res = ses.post('http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/login', data=Payload, headers=header)
    print(res.content)
```

Note: Username/password are correct but still facing same issue.

Comment: The obvious explanation is that the username/password are wrong.

Comment: Also, "200 OK" response just means the page was delivered successfully.  It doesn't mean the page did what you WANTED.

Comment: @JohnGordon username/password is correct but I dont know why its again redirecting to login page, if I put redirection to false then the status code is 301, thanks for the reply

Comment: Well, because 301 means "I want to redirect".

Comment: Issue sloved thanks for the comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I figured out myself the URL I provided was 'http://xxxxxxxxx.com/login,'[http] but it should be 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/login.'[https].
Here is the modified code:

res = ses.post('https://xxxxxxxxx.com/login', data=Payload, headers=header)